# SliverAppBar: How to keep native view alive during scrolling?

Tags: flutter

I would like to display a native view (HeaderContainer) in the flexibleSpace of a SliverAppBar and prevent it from rebuild.

```
return new Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 180,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: HeaderContainer(),
                    // HeaderContainer is a native View (AndroidView)
                ),
             ),
             SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([content]),
            )
        ]
    )
);
```

Unfortunately the HeaderContainer() gets destroyed when it becomes invisible during scrolling.
The creating of HeaderContainer() is quite expensive and took some time.

Is there a possibility to keep this widget in memory and prevent it from beeing destroyed while scrolling?

**update:**

The problem of rebuilding the HeaderContaienr after scrolling back is only an issue with native views (e.g. AndroidView).

---

**some investigations:**

FlexibleSpaceBar uses this lines to add the child:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    if (opacity > 0.0) {    <-- !
        children.add( ... );
    }
```

Therefore the child is only added to the tree if opacity is greater as zero and gets removed (and destroyed) if opacity is zero. This causes the rebuild after scrolling back.

I ended up in a custom flexibleSpace widget where the child is allways added to the view tree.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you `setState` your widget tree will rebuild to match any change. Everytime you scroll, a new frame needs to be rendered, thus the performance you're complaining of. You have 3 options that comes in mind:

1.You may want to use a `const` constructor on your `HeaderContainer`

2.You can try to assign your `HeaderContainer` as a final variable in
    your `build` method so it will only rebuild the dependencies that
    change if the current widget instance stays the same, as such:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final header = HeaderContainer();

  return new Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 180,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: header,
                ),
             ),
                   SliverList(
                   delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([content]),
               )
           ]
       )
  );
```

3.Or you can add this `header` as a property of your stateful widget
    but have in mind that this will break hot-reload for that widget
    (header).

Comment: You would need to move `final header = HeaderContainer();` out of `build()` for that to work as you describe. In your example a new `HeaderContainer()` is created every time `build()` is called.

Comment: That’s the option 3. In the option 2 where it is inside the build method you’re right and it will only rebuild if you setState or even rebuild the parent widget, but actually won’t if you’re using streams in some of the widgets of the tree, just to clarify.

Comment: this all is true for flutter widgets but does not help for native views.